# Declaring a function conditional of operating system

Tags: vb.net, function, dllimport, declare

I need to declare an external function according to the type of operating system. If 64bit declare the function from the 64bit dll instead if 32bit declare it works from the 32

```
Shared isOp64Bit As Boolean = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem

#Const WIN64 = isOp64Bit

#If WIN64 Then
    Declare Function Init_MatrixAPI Lib "matrix64.dll" () As Short
#Else
    Declare Function Init_MatrixAPI Lib "matrix32.dll" () As Short
#End If
```

This code does not work

Comment: How could you possibly set a constant that is required at compile time based on a variable that isn't known until run time? What you're trying to do is impossible. You need to build two versions of your app.

Comment: `GetProcAddress` and then `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`.

Comment: I read on msdn that it is possible to do it, but I do not understand how  [link] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: That link is for VBA in Office. Not applicable to this question. Do it the way I said.

Comment: Then again, perhaps the best way forward is not to have different names for the DLLs. Same name, different directories. Use explicit LoadLibrary with full path before calling any function in the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it declares both with different names and only calls the one it needs.

This handles the situation also when you compile as x86 in 64-bit system (in case you ever need to do that for a certain reason).

```
Declare Function Init_MatrixAPI64 Lib "matrix64.dll" Alias "Init_MatrixAPI" () As Short
Declare Function Init_MatrixAPI32 Lib "matrix32.dll" Alias "Init_MatrixAPI" () As Short

Public Function Init_MatrixAPICaller() As Short
    If IntPtr.Size = 8 Then
        Return Init_MatrixAPI64()
    Else
        Return Init_MatrixAPI32()
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: This is a very labour intensive approach.

Comment: He mentioned only one function...so not in that case